# Laravel 5.1 Won't save date into database set as 00-00-00 00:00:00

Tags: date, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I'm sending dates up using this Bootstrap [datetimepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) with a format of `MMM D, YYY` created by [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/), which can't submit a different format than what is displayed to the user by default.

So on the server-side I added an mutator for the date in the model:

```php
public function setStartDateAttribute($startDate) {
    //dd(Carbon::parse($startDate)->toDateTimeString());
    return Carbon::parse($startDate)->toDateTimeString();
}
```

Which when I `dd` the value looks like it should `2015-10-22 00:00:00`, but it saves the date as `0000-00-00 00:00:00` or it just isn't setting the date at all, which I don't understand.

I don't want to change how the timestamps are formatted in the database so I didn't set `$dateFormat` and set `'start_date'` in the `$dates` array of the Model.  Thought an mutator seemed easier.  The field is set to `date()` in the migration file, and I'm pretty sure I've done this before and it just worked. So I tried it in the my controller without the mutator and the same line works:

```php
public function update(TournamentRequest $request, $tournamentId)
{
    // Update a tournament with all fillable data, and persist to database
    $tournament = Tournament::find($tournamentId)->fill($request->except('start_date'));
    $tournament->start_date = Carbon::parse($request->start_date)->toDateTimeString();
    $tournament->save();

    return Redirect::route('dashboard.tournaments.index');
}
```

Why does the same code work inside the controller without the mutator setup in the Model, but not work when using the mutator?

Comment: Erm... Why is your mutator just returning the value rather than actually setting your start_date attribute?

Comment: Haha @MattGibson, oh man I have been staring at this and working on other stuff wondering what was wrong... thanks!  oh the shame.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you make a setter method for your attribute. Note: you don't return anything, you just assign a value to the attribute:

```php
public function setStartDateAttribute($startDate) {
    $this->attributes['start_date'] = Carbon::parse($startDate)->toDateTimeString();
}
```

That's assuming you want to set a field named `start_date` in your table.